# How can I make a number randomly appear a certain percent of the time - repeatedly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am making a game where I want fluctuating damage. There are two enemies. For enemy one, they lose a constant amount of health (5 points). For enemy two, there is a chance that the player will inflict a small amount of damage 80% of the time (3 points) and a large amount of damage 20% of the time (10 points).

I tried using choice from a group of numbers, but I found that it will choose one of these random numbers (3 for example) and will stick with it until the game restarts. I want the damage number to change each time the player attacks so that it looks more like "-3, -3, -3, -10, -3" for example.

In the main loop I have:

```
hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.enemy1s, self.shards, False, True)
for hit in hits:
    hit.health -= SHARD_DAMAGE1
    hit.vel = vec(0, 0)
hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.enemy2s, self.shards, False, True)
for hit in hits:
    hit.health -= SHARD_DAMAGE1
    hit.vel = vec(0, 0)
```

The SHARD_DAMAGE is defined separately in another file as:

```
CONSTANT = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
RAND = [3, 3, 3, 3, 10]
SHARD_DAMAGE1 = choice(CONSTANT)
SHARD_DAMAGE2 = choice(RAND)
```

At the very top of both files I have: `from random import uniform, choice`.

Like I said, the game will lock onto 3 or 10 and make that the damage until the entire thing is restarted. Even if I were to have 5 random numbers, it only picks one until I restart.

Comment: use `choice` when player attack, not in another file - `hit.health -= choice(CONSTANT)`

Comment: I agree with @furas, you need to call the method that performs the hit, as when you init a file, as I suspect you do the choice method is running once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when a variable gets assigned a random number, the program is only referring to this stored value that has been picked once. When a choice is made, like here:

```
SHARD_DAMAGE1 = choice(CONSTANT)
```

The value stored in `SHARD_DAMAGE1` will never get reassigned because `SHARD_DAMAGE1 = choice(CONSTANT)` is read only once at the beginning.

As suggested in a comment, you would need to make a *random* choice every time a hit is needed like so:

```
hit.health -= choice(CONSTANT)
```

Proceeding this way, a new calculation will be performed each time a hit will be given.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any need to hold a list of pre-defined numbers.

Write a small function that takes into account the type of the enemy.  Then for the "other" type, depend the damage calculation around your 20% / 80% split:

```
def getDamage( enemy_type ):
    if ( enemy_type == enemy.TYPE_ONE ):
        damage = DAMAGE_NORMAL #5
    elif ( enemy_type == enemy.TYPE_TWO ):
        if ( random.randint( 1, 100 ) > 80 ):  # Critical hit?
            damage = DAMAGE_LARGE  #10
        else:
            damage = DAMAGE_SMALL  #3
    else:
        # random damage
        damage = random.randint( 1, 5 )
    return damage
```